# what is the difference between freemarker 2.3.21 and freemarker 2.3.26-incubating

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to update Freemarker from 2.3.21 to 2.3.26-incubating. but, I do not know what features have improved or added or edited. I need to write an article about main improvement between these tow version. what should I write?

I want main improvement between tow versions 2.3.21 and 2.3.26-incubating  of Freemarker. please, help me:

Comment: Just read the changelog for this version: http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3_26.html and versions 2.3.22, 23, 24, 25.

Comment: @StephaneM thank you... but I want a list of the most important changes...(:

Answer (score 1):

As @StephaneM said, there's a detailed [change log](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_versions.html). And it will be long for such a huge version range, but all changes should be backward compatible. But the most popular new features were probably these: [Automatic escaping](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html) (i.e. "output formats"), [new `#list` features](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref.directive.list) (key-value listing, `#items`, `#else`, `#sep`), [loop variable built-ins](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html), [`?api`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_buitin_api_and_has_api) (to work around historical issues with `Map`-s...), [custom number- and date formats](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html), `+=` and `++` operators in assignments, possibility of escaping of `-` (and `:` and `.`) in identifiers with `\`.

Comment: @ddenkany could you explain Automatic escaping?? I have read it's tutorial several times but I can not found it out...):

Comment: Concretely what don't you understand in it? BTW, there's also a heavily simplified version of it: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html#dgui_quickstart_template_autoescaping